# How can there be static addresses in C/C++ programs?

Tags: windows, memory, memory-management, operating-system

I've been looking a bit into [Cheat Engine](http://www.cheatengine.org/), which allows you to inspect and manipulate the memory of running processes on Windows: You scan for variables based on their value, then you can modify them, e.g. to cheat in a game.

In order to write a bot or something similar, you need to find a static address for the variable you want to change - i.e. one that stays the same if the process is restarted. The method for that goes roughly like this:

1. Look for the address of the variable you're interested in, searching by value
2. Look for code using that address, e.g. to find the address of the struct it belongs to (since struct offsets are fixed)
3. Look for another pointer pointing to that pointer until you find one with a static address (shows as green in Cheat Engine)

It seems to work just fine judging from the tutorials I've looked at, but I have trouble understanding *why* it works.

**Don't all variables, including global static ones, get a pretty random address at runtime time?**

Bonus questions:

1. How can Cheat Engine tell if an address is static (i.e. will stay the same on restart)?
2. A tutorial referred to the fact that many older and some modern games (e.g. Call of Duty 4) use *only* static addresses. How is that possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will answer the bonus questions first because they introduce some concepts you may need to know to understand the answer for the main question.

Answering the first bonus question is easy if you know how an executable file works: all the global/static variables are inside the `.data` section, in which the .exe stores the address offset for the section so Cheat Engine just checks if the variable is in this address range (from this section to the next one).

For the second question, it is possible to use only static addresses, but that is nearly impossible for a game. Even the older ones. What the tutorial creator was probably trying to say is that all variables that he wants, actually had a static pointer pointing to them. But solely by the fact that you create a local variable, or even pass an argument to a function, their values are being stored into the stack. That's why it is nearly impossible to have a "static-only" program. Even if you compile a program that actually doesn't do anything, it will probably have some stuff being stored in the stack.

For the whole question itself, not all dynamic address variables are pointed by a global variable. It depends totally on the programmer. I can create a local variable and never assign its address to a global/static pointer in a C program, for example. The only certain way to find that address in this case is to actually know the code when the variable was first assigned a value in the stack.

Some variables have a dynamic address because they are just local variables, which are stored in the stack the first time they have a value assigned to them.

Some other variables have a static address because they are declared either as a global or a static variable to the compiler. These variables have a fixed address offset that is part of the `.data` section in the executable file.

The executable file has a fixed offset address for each section inside it, and the `.data` section is no exception.

But it is worth to note that the offset inside the executable itself is fixed. In the operating system things might be different (all random addresses), but that is the job of an OS, abstracting this kind of stuff for you (creating the executable's virtual address space in this case). So it just looks like static variables are actually static, but only inside the executable's memory space. On the RAM things might be anywhere.

Finally, it is difficult to try to explain this to you because you'll have to understand how executable files work. A good start would be to search for some explanations regarding low-level programming, like stack frame, calling conventions, the Assembly language itself and how compilers use some well-known techniques to manage functions (scopes in general), global/static/local/constant variables, and the memory system (sections, the stack, etc.), and maybe some research into PE (and even ELF) files.

Comment: My bad, I did some tests with static variables to see if their offsets are fixed and it seemed they aren't, but I had an error in there :( So yes, static variables seem to be at fixed offsets generally, that answers the bonus questions. As for the main question - what about a program where all data is kept on the stack/heap with no static pointers to that? That's pretty typical in C++ at least. How I see it, if there's no static variable _somewhere_ that points to this data, it's not possible to get a static address for it - but it seems to work for pretty much all games.

Comment: Cheat Engine is not only looking for "static addresses" when you do a pointer scan. That's actually why you need to run the scan many times in different states in the game (and different runs) to get a address that seems like will serve the purpose for the states in the game that you have passed while doing the scan. But it is not guaranteed that this pointer will always hold the address you want. So basically it searches for static and local pointers.

Comment: But then why does a local pointer is always the same offset? Probably because it was allocated so early in the stack, that it stays in the first scopes opened early in the game, maybe before the main loop, which will stay valid until the game closes enough scopes to then make this pointer hold garbage memory.

Comment: What I meant was: From all the tutorials I've seen, it sounds as if there's _always_ a static address people can use to get to the data they want, to write bots and trainers. But I doubt most games actually keep global static pointers to the player instance etc. So how could that work?

Comment: That's what I answered. These are not static addresses, but only some early allocated local variables (think `main()` for example) that stay alive pretty much while the game is running. If the scope is not destroyed, then the stack does not grow, making the address valid until it actually closes the scope for this function.

Comment: That's also why sometimes you need more than 1 depth pointer to the address you want. Say for example a pointer to a pointer to the address. This is needed in case Cheat Engine doesn't find a local variable with life long enough to be used throughout the whole game. Then you need to find all the pointer that point to this pointer, and check if these actually have a longer life (the best case being if they were declared as static/global or in some early functions like `main`).

Comment: OK, me and my tests again. Testing with local pointers (in main()) to heap objects - the addresses are indeed at static offsets relative to the processes base pointer. So that explains it all!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand it, variables declared static have a permanent offset within the program data. This means that when the program is loaded into RAM, the offset of the variable will always be the same. Because the beginning address of the program is known globally, finding a static variable based on offset, as you mentioned, should be a trivial task. Therefore, while a pointer to a static variable might be random in the scheme of things, its offset to the beginning of program memory should remain the same no matter when the program starts. So Cheat Engine (though I don't know the software) most likely stores the offset of the static variable, and then when the software starts, applies this logic to find that variable.

As to how it can tell it's a static variable in the first place... well, this is partially a guess, but when you declare a variable static in C, I'm assuming the compiler/linker puts some kind of flag so the OS knows that it's a static variable. It could also be that all static variables are stored in a certain way, or at a certain address offset, for all programs compiled for a certain target system. Again, not too sure about that, but from what I understand about memory management, that seems to make the most sense. With these assumptions, it's quite possible for a program to contain solely static variables. The difference is that memory is assigned statically at program runtime, as a opposed to dynamically (as with a call to malloc() or similar). If the variables were stored dynamically, I'm sure there'd be a way to find them easily, so I don't think it matters to Cheat Engine whether or not a variable is static or not. However, as I'm assuming Cheat Engine wants to modify a game upon startup (just like the old GameSharks used to... ahh, miss those days) it's probably more reliable to modify variables that are static, instead of trying to locate pointers and disassemble the code, etc. etc.

If you're interested in learning more, I'd recommend checking out something like [this tutorial over at OSDev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_management)!